# gdfs to graph and vise versa

Tags: python, osmnx

The following happens when I use python's `osmnx` as follows:

```
graph = osmnx.graph_from_polygon(Data.bbox)

gdf_nodes, gdf_edges = osmnx.save_load.graph_to_gdfs(
        graph,
        nodes=True, edges=True,
        node_geometry=True,
        fill_edge_geometry=True)
print(gdf_edges['u']) # prints the values nicely

graph2 = osmnx.save_load.gdfs_to_graph(gdf_nodes, gdf_edges) # misses 'v' and 'u' column in gdf_nodes
```

Then I get the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\jpelda\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\osmnx\save_load.py", line 513, in gdfs_to_graph
    G.add_edge(u=row['u'], v=row['v'], key=row['key'], **attrs)

TypeError: add_edge() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'u_for_edge' and 'v_for_edge'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you're using the latest released versions of OSMnx (0.8.1 as of today) and NetworkX (2.1 as of today). Your code snippet works fine. Complete working example:

```
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox
print(ox.__version__)
print(nx.__version__)
graph = ox.graph_from_place('Piedmont, California, USA', network_type='drive')
gdf_nodes, gdf_edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(
        graph,
        nodes=True, edges=True,
        node_geometry=True,
        fill_edge_geometry=True)
graph2 = ox.gdfs_to_graph(gdf_nodes, gdf_edges)
```

After 0.13.0 (2020-05-25)

`ox.gdfs_to_graph()` has been replaced with `ox.graph_from_gdfs()`

If your OSMnx's version is after 0.13.0, please using the code below:

```
graph2 = ox.graph_from_gdfs(gdf_nodes, gdf_edges)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import networkx as nx

nx.Graph.add_edge(row['u'], row['v'])
```

works!

Obviously u and v can not be given as optionals! Did that change for the new networkx release?

Answer (score 0):

Using `networkx==3.2.1` and `osmnx==`

Here is the implementation:

```
import networkx as nx # 3.2.1
import osmnx as ox    # 1.7.1
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # 3.8.1

osm_file_path = './map2.osm'

#graph = ox.graph_from_xml(osm_file_path, encoding='utf-8')
graph = ox.graph_from_place('Chittagong, Chittagong, BD', network_type='drive')
gdf_nodes, gdf_edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(
        graph,
        nodes=True, edges=True,
        node_geometry=True,
        fill_edge_geometry=True
)


#print(gdf_nodes)
#print(gdf_edges)

graph2 = ox.graph_from_gdfs(gdf_nodes, gdf_edges)

#print(type(graph2))
#print(graph2)


nx.draw(graph2)
plt.show()
```

ref:

- https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/issues/526
- https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/blob/ef5d465448b1097a89615bd2bbaa3546a54e0f6b/CHANGELOG.md?plain=1#L271